# Reject 2-digit year with Spring @DateTimeFormat(style = "M-")

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

My web-application is using Spring (spring-boot 2.4.2) and supports multiple locales (date formats). To format/parse Dates my form-object contains for example:

```
@DateTimeFormat(style = "M-")
private Date birthdate;
```

It is currently possible to enter 2-digit-year: When entering (german locale) "25.06.86" it is converted to "24.06.0086".
I can't use pattern-attribute as I have to support multiple locales.

I want to show a form error when a 2-digit year is provided. How can I reject 2-digit-years?